# RijndaelManaged supports 128-256 bit key, what key size the default constructor generator?

Tags: c#, aes, rijndaelmanaged

For new RijndaelManaged(), the documentation says it supports keys of 128 bits and up to 256 bits.

When you instantiate new RijndaelManaged(), it creates the Key and IV for you.

What size does it default to, 128 bits?

Answer (score 23):

The default key size is 256 bits, while the default blocksize is 128 bits.

Comment: The documentation confirms: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.keysize?view=netstandard-2.1&viewFallbackFrom=netframework-4.8